# Use npm and wp-env to make production bundle

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

Does anyone have a webpack config modification or `@wordpress/wp-scripts` extension that takes `npm run build` and then bundles everything up into a nice little .tgz or .zip without all of the extra development stuff? [WPRig](https://wprig.io) does this nicely at the theme level, but I'd like it for simple plugin development. Needless to say, I'm a complete n00b at webpack.

Answer (score 1):

[`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-pack) can do this for you. You can configure what it puts in the tarball with a .npmignore file or with the [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#files) field in package.json.

An example of the `files` field:

```
"files": ["*.json", "readme.txt", "my-plugin.php", "build/*"],
```

With the above in package.json, running `npm pack` will produce a .tgz with only the files from that list.